# In which format would articles for websites and native apps be stored?

Tags: android, ios, native

In which format would e.g. news websites who also have *native* Android and iOS apps store their articles? (Original question: Can native apps read/process HTML?, but that produced answers that do not answer the first question.)

Comment: you can do a webview

Comment: @DroiDev - I'm quite savvy when it comes to HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP, but I'm a nono when it comes to native-app development. What is that, doing a webview?

Comment: See below answer. You are better off developing it with react native if you know html, css, and js.

Comment: THey could store them in any format they wanted.  THey have an app, they could convert it on the fly.

Comment: @GabeSechan - Sure. XML, SQL, JSON, everything is possible, theoretically. But which format would they use?

Comment: @FrankConijn Unanswerable.  Whatever their devs thought best.  Which we can't even make a reasonable guess at, as we don't know their full usecases.

Comment: @GabeSechan - A developer who has worked for a publisher with a website plus native apps should be able to answer it. So it is far from unanswerable, even though different answers may describe different options. And don't mind that, as long they put some effort into answering it.

Comment: @FrankConijn No, they can't.  Because the answer is likely different  at any publisher out there.  There is no technical reason only one would be used.  And if you're asking for the best, that's off topic as primarily opinion based (and way too broad as even the start of a discussion on use cases could take pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally implemented such a system in the past: we have used a subset of HTML, i.e. it was stored as HTML but only specific tags and combinations of tags were allowed.

To ensure it the system checked and cleaned all HTML before storing it.

On iOS and Android, we've used the according web views to display the HTML. CSS was added to HTML at display time for proper styling. The CSS was different for Android, iOS and web.

Comment: That's what I mean! Thanks a lot. A next question: That subset, did you define that yourself or are there global specifications for it, like the W3C specifications for HTML5?

Comment: We defined it ourselves by just using the minimal set that we needed. Over time we slightly expanded it. If I'm not mistaken we started with H2, H3, P, BLOCKQUOTE, IMG, I, B, UL, LI, and A and some additional rules, e.g. IMG tag must be the only element within a P element.

Comment: Got it. And could you use IDs and classes as well?

Comment: You certainly can use classes (you probably want to restrict it to a a few specific ones). I guess you can use IDs as well - I just can't image what for at the moment. I also remember that we checked, cleaned and sometimes replaced the attributes. For images, they had to come from our own image database. So we stored them like `src="library/3172"` and replaced the attribute value with a full link before displaying it.

Comment: OK. And am I right in thinking that your system would store the article contents in bare form, so only the part that on a full webpage would be between the body tags? And that with (the equivalent of) server-side includes or AJAX calls the contents would be loaded by the website and the native apps?

Comment: Yes, only an HTML fragment (without HTML, HEAD and BODY) is being saved as text. In the apps, the text was loaded using a REST API, i.e. using native code and then creating the web view once the HTML fragment is available. You could also use Javascript with AJAX instead.

Comment: Great. You've clarified a matter that's been puzzling me for quite a while. One more question (for now): have you ever heard of other systems being used with which websites and native apps load *article* contents? Tabular database, XML, JSON? I can't imagine how that would be a user-friendly system, but just wondering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, with a **Webview**

You can find some up to date documentation and examples how to use it:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Comment: Does that mean that e.g. news websites who also have native apps would store their articles in normal, full HTML pages, and the native apps would simply load those pages? (See the rephrased question.)

Comment: You've probably come across these types of apps, who are really websites. The UX is just bad. This is a wrapper for HTML, best analogy would be an embed of a website inside a "native" app. Tbh don't do it, if you are good at JS/TS/CSS you're better off doing a React Native app.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. But that would sound more like web or hybrid apps to me? Because would e.g. large journals publish native apps with a bad UXs?

Comment: You changed the actual question, and this makes it a little confusing, can you clearly ask want you want? Because the way I see it, you really want to parse it to JSON and use a standard REST api?

Comment: If you'd still find the rephrased question unclear, please have a look at the Q&A I'm having with Codo. That should make it crystal clear.